# Error to verify a password when I run the userform

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have this code to valid a username and a password but every try I make to see if it´s working does not find the password and I can not find the error in the code for that, I don´t know if I need to set an specific sheet where the password is settle or what. If you can help me I´ll be thankfull.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim usuario As String
    Dim password As Variant
    Dim IDExistente
    Dim DatoEncontrado
    Dim Rango As Range
    IDExistente = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Cines").Range("B:B"), Me.TextBox1.Value)
    Set Rango = Sheets("Cines").Range("B:C")
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
       MsgBox "Se requiere del ID y la contraseña para obtener los folios", vbOKOnly, "Aviso"
       TextBox1.SetFocus
    ElseIf IDExistente = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Debes ingresar un ID valido para obtener los folios favor de validar.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    ElseIf IDExistente = 1 Then
        DatoEncontrado = Rango.Find(What:=Me.TextBox1.Value, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
        Contrasena = CStr(Range(DatoEncontrado).Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Value)
        If CStr(Range(DatoEncontrado).Value) = Me.TextBox1.Value And Contrasena = Me.TextBox2.Value Then
           Hoja1.Range("E1") = TextBox1.Text
           Hoja1.Range("E2") = TextBox2.Text
        Else: MsgBox "La contraseña no es correcta favor de validar.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
           TextBox2.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code using code tags (3 back-ticks before & 3 back-ticks after. To make it easier to read. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredGeek I´m new on this Blog, and with the error could you help me??

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes I think the problem is there to, in the code I have this: DatoEncontrado = Rango.Find(What:=Me.TextBox1.Value, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
Contrasena = CStr(Range(DatoEncontrado).Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Value).....so  once i find "DatoEcontrado" I use the samne value to specify the code to move one column to find the correct value of the password. There is when de error appears.

Comment: What error are you getting? 91? Is the correct/expected sheet active when `Range.Find` runs? You must qualify `Range.Find` with a proper `Worksheet` object reference, and also make sure the result of `Range.Find` isn't `Nothing` before using it.